# BinaryReader missing values

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Im using theBinaryReader to place the elements of a binary file into a List of Int16.
But the count value of elements read back from the binary file is incorrect. 
Here is the Reader:

```
            using (var file = File.OpenRead(openFileName))
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(file))
            {
                int count = reader.ReadInt16();
                    this.view.Data = new List<Int16>(count);
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    this.view.Data.Add(reader.ReadInt16());
            }
```

I know that when im saving my binary file that the view.Data list constains 19000 elements, but then I look at the count value during the read method shown above its telling me that count is only 134 :(

here is the writter:

```
                    using (var file = File.Create(fileName))
                    using (view.Writer = new BinaryWriter(file))
                    {
                        foreach (Int16 dataItem in view.Data)
                        {
                            view.Writer.Write(dataItem);
                        }
                    }
```

Total file size after write is 40KB, and when in debug mode the view.Data contains 19000 when savign, and only 134 when reading?

could anyone please help

Comment: what is the file size of the file you are reading from?

Comment: Clearly there's a mismatch between the reading and writing code.  Or the writing code doesn't start at the beginning the file.  Post the writing code if that doesn't help.  You can use a hex viewer to get a second opinion of what's in the file.

Comment: @Hans - that's why I was asking for the file size - it should be 38002 bytes if it really contains a count and 19000 Int16 values.

Comment: What does the file look like if you open it in a Hex viewer? Also, if this is your file format, then do you really need that count at the front?

Comment: You forget to write the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not writing out the count, it should be like this to match your reading code:

```
                using (var file = File.Create(fileName))
                using (view.Writer = new BinaryWriter(file))
                {
                    Int16 count = (Int16) view.Data.Count;
                    view.Writer.Write(count);
                    foreach (Int16 dataItem in view.Data)
                    {
                        view.Writer.Write(dataItem);
                    }
                }
```

Probably the first value `view.Data[0]` has a value of `134`, that's why are you currently are only reading that many.

Comment: Not exactly.  This could be a good way to repro the OP's problem.  The Count value is likely to be written as an Int32 if it isn't cast.

Comment: You are right first value in the list was 134, so how can I overcome this?

Comment: No, any List<> has a Count property that's Int32.  It doesn't depend on the type argument.  Consider `List<string>`